# create/sign/send raw transaction from specific Wallet account

Tags: bitcoind

I've been playing with the `createrawtransaction`, `signrawtransaction`, and `sendrawtransaction` Bitcoin calls.

Let's say there are two accounts in my Wallet: Account1 and the default `""` account. Let's also say account balances are `"" = 0.00000000` and `Account1 = 0.50000000` and that the only UTXO in my Wallet references a Bitcoin address owned by Account1 as the output address and is in the amount of `0.50000000`.

When I create, sign, and send the transaction to another Wallet, the account balances appear as `"" = -0.50000000` and `Account1 = 0.50000000`, and the balance of my Wallet equals the obvious `0.00000000`.

Is there any way, when creating/signing/sending a transaction, that I can specify which account to send it from?

I'm familiar with the `sendfromaccount` call that would accomplish this, but I want to create my transactions manually so I can control the change (when necessary) and the transaction fees.

Comment: FYI the accounts feature [is being deprecated](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3816) in v0.11 and will probably be removed sometime thereafter because it has many [weaknesses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained#Account_Weaknesses) and misunderstandings as to how it works: [1](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/2079) [2](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/6042) [3](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/4572)

Comment: If you must use the account feature (*after* reading up on its weaknesses), create and send your raw tx and then use the "move" command to fix the account balances. Note that this won't be an [atomic operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) (yet another weakness...).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and you should also mind, that the accounting system in bitcoin-core has been marked for deprecation.

The rawtx commands to not cooperate with accounts.

If possible, you should avoid accounts.